# why cpython has list_reverse and PyList_Reverse

Tags: c, list, cpython

I am recently reading CPython source code.
In CPython3.11, I found that in listobject implementation.
There are two methods that does the same thing

One is first in clinic check for signature named `list_reverse`
Another is PyList_reverse

```c
// clinic
static PyObject *
list_reverse(PyListObject *self, PyObject *Py_UNUSED(ignored))
{
    return list_reverse_impl(self);
}

// impl

static PyObject *
list_reverse_impl(PyListObject *self)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=482544fc451abea9 input=eefd4c3ae1bc9887]*/
{
    if (Py_SIZE(self) > 1)
        reverse_slice(self->ob_item, self->ob_item + Py_SIZE(self));
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

int
PyList_Reverse(PyObject *v)
{
    PyListObject *self = (PyListObject *)v;

    if (v == NULL || !PyList_Check(v)) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return -1;
    }
    if (Py_SIZE(self) > 1)
        reverse_slice(self->ob_item, self->ob_item + Py_SIZE(self));
    return 0;
}

/* Reverse a slice of a list in place, from lo up to (exclusive) hi. */
static void
reverse_slice(PyObject **lo, PyObject **hi)
{
    assert(lo && hi);
    
    --hi;
    while (lo < hi) {
        PyObject *t = *lo;
        *lo = *hi;
        *hi = t;
        ++lo;
        --hi;
    }
}
```

In clinic, it seems to be defining the second one `list_reverse` as standard method

```c
#define LIST_REVERSE_METHODDEF    \
    {"reverse", (PyCFunction)list_reverse, METH_NOARGS, list_reverse__doc__},
```

I did some google. It says that `PyList_reverse` is part of C-API.

I did not really get that because `list_reverse` is also written in C and they both used `reverse_slice` as kernel.

So why? Is it like one of them is going to be removed in later version?

Answer why there are two "redundant function"

Comment: Presumably because `PyList_reverse` has a nicer interface when working with C. It will return a traditional C success (`0`)/failure(`-1`), rather than returning `Py_None` or raising a Python exception.